# How increase memory of org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am running the Eclipse ant runner from command line in the following way:

```
set LAUNCHER=%ECLIPSE_SDK%\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.3.0.jar

%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -jar %LAUNCHER% -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -propertyfile %PROPERTIES% -buildfile build.xml
```

How do I increase the memory provided to this jvm instance ? I am asking this because I am facing `OutOfMemory` errors in the heap space and adding -vmargs -Xmx512m to the command line didn't fixed the issue

In order to see if -vmargs are taken into account I simply wrote the folowing task:

```
public class DisplayTask extends Task {

    @Override
    public void execute() throws BuildException {
        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1000000);
    }
}
```

and just launch it in my build.xml (using taskedf to define the task). The output is always 66 whatever I put in -vmargs -Xmx ....

Comment: Can you post the actual out of memory error you are receiving?  Is it PermGen-related?

Comment: no it's related to heap space. I updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it, the solution is to add -Xmx512m option **just after** the java.exe as folowing:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe **-Xmx512m** -jar %LAUNCHER% -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -propertyfile %PROPERTIES% -buildfile build.xml
```

This is finally NORMAL. Only the eclipse.exe executable understands the -vmargs flag; when I run java -jar LAUNCHER then I am creating the VM and must thus specify the arguments myself.

Answer (score 0):

you could try setting the ANT_OPTS system variable: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Ant+opts

Comment: I am not running the classic ant.bat file but I am using Eclipse ant runner.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using native Equinox Launcher (which you're not but probably should - Eclipse ships with carefully crafted VM args) you should know about `--launcher.appendVmargs` parameter (see [The Eclipse runtime options](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html), [Eclipse/149994](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=149994) and [eclipse.ini](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) for details

```
 # eclipse --launcher.appendVmargs -vmargs  -Xmx512m -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -propertyfile %PROPERTIES% -buildfile build.xml
```